# Meaning of "mkfs.ext3 -cc" error report

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks, mkfs

I'm trying to format a supposedly defective hard disk using "mkfs.ext3 -cc /dev/sda1" on a partition that spans over the entire disk.

I wish to understand the meaning of the ongoing error report in mkfs.ext3's command output, on the last line: "...(109/0/0 errors)". I didn't find information about these three values in man pages and other sources.

This is the ongoing output of the running command:

```
# mkfs.ext3 -cc /dev/sda1
mke2fs 1.42.4 (12-June-2012)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
61054976 inodes, 244190390 blocks
12209519 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
7453 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups saved in blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848

Checking with model 0xaa: done
Reading and comparision:  94.30% done, 24:09:03 elapsed. (109/0/0 errors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all else fails, use the actual [sources](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/badblocks.c?h=v1.42.4#n1297)! There, we see that the fields being printed are:

```
fprintf(stderr,
                _("Pass completed, %u bad blocks found. (%d/%d/%d errors)\n"),
                bb_count, num_read_errors, num_write_errors, num_corruption_errors);
```

In other words, they are the number of read errors, write errors, and corruption errors.